# Web form for markters in Sitecore template

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I'm trying to create a Sitecore template which would have a field that is Web Form for Marketers which could be set by user. I'd prefer it to be as a field, however I don't how to do that. Is there anyone who could help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as the Web Forms for Marketers data is captured directly in the `WebForms` database, not the `master` database, so you can't apply a custom form into a field. The form is actually generated on the front-end via a custom control (I believe its called the Form Interpreter).

Comment: Thanks for tip. However, I found other solution how to do that. I created placeholder to keep content and added WFM item there. Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: Right, that's how WFFM works. You didn't actually implement WFFM into a field which is what you wanted to do. Have you read the documentation on how to use WFFM? There may be more that you don't know about it. It's available on the SDN.